# If a set of vectors are all orthogonal to each other, would shortened versions of those vectors also be orthogonal?

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

Say I have a set of vectors, $v_{0\ldots n}$, all of which are orthogonal to each other and all of which are of length *$m$*.

If I took a portion of each vector (same start and end indices for each), would those portions also be orthogonal to each other?

e.g. would $v_0\left[0:\frac m2\right]$, $v_1\left[0:\frac m2\right]$, $v_2\left[0:\frac m2\right]$, etc. all be orthogonal to each other, and if so, does that hold true regardless of the start and end indices (as long as they're consistent)?

Apologies for the mathematical notation, I'm not certain how to represent a subset/slice of a vector properly, so I wrote it the way we do in software.

Comment: Yes. The dot product is bilinear and as such if it is $0$ for some pair of vectors it is zero for every rescaling of either of them

Comment: Not in general. That truncation is a projection to the coordinate subspace of those first few coordinates. When you project the angle between vectors can change.

Comment: No.  Take $[1,1]^T$ and $[1,-1]^T$ which are orthogonal, truncate them to $[1]^T, [1]^T$ and clearly you do not get an orthogonal result.

Comment: You got some "yes" answers and some "no" answers, and it all hangs on what you mean by "shortened" versions of vectors. Did you just keep the _direction_ but halved the _magnitude_? In other words you've changed each $v_i$ to $\frac{1}{2}v_i$? If so, they will stay orthogonal simply because their dot product ($v_i\cdot v_j=0$) will turn into $\frac{1}{2}v_i\cdot\frac{1}{2}v_j=\frac{1}{4}(v_i\cdot v_j)=\frac{1}{4}0=0$. This is the essence of the first comment above. If you meant something else, then can you please try to explain what it is.

Comment: Thank you, @Henry understood what I meant and answered clearly with a counterexample.

Comment: @TShiong, please stop editing all these old questions, bumping them to the front page, bumping newer questions off the page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah, but older questions also need some attention and some formating for better readability

Comment: @TSh, sure, but, please, do three or four a day, not a dozen in an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $v_1=(1,1,0)$ and $v_2=(1,-1,0)$. Are [taking only first and third coordinates] $(1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ orthogonal to each other?